# reaching subnets from vmware guest

Tags: networking, vmware-vsphere

I have a vmware-vsphere host with one linux guest Jupiter. Jupiter has internal ip 192.168.2.2 andcan communicate with the internet (outside world) fine (the outside world reaching Jupiter via its public IP). Jupiter can also communicate with other hosts on the same subnet 192.168.2.0/24 (other hosts can see Jupiter on its 192.168.2.2 address). The router is on 192.168.2.1.

There is also another subnet 10.0.0.0/24. Jupiter cannot reach this. no ping, nothing.

I only have access to Jupiter, so I don't know how the router is set up or how the rest of the network looks like (company secrets blablabla). Their sysadmin is saying the problem is with Jupiter not having vmware tools installed. I'm saying the problem must be with routing on the 192.168.2.1 router but they refuse to show me any information about the router.

Are they correct there is a problem with vmware, such as vmware tools?

```
Jupiter:
eth0:
ip 192.168.2.2/24 
broadcast  192.168.2.0.255 
netmask 255.255.255.0

route table:
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.2
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not likely to be related to the presence, or absence of the vmware tools, or bugs within the vmware tools.

The important thing to remember about virtualisation when solving problems like this is that *nothing magical happens* to your network, good or bad, just because someone took a network diagram and said "by the way, these hosts are now virtual".

Your computers, both host and guest, are on a different subnet to the rest of the network. If you cannot see the rest of the network then there is a switch configuration issue (whether routing at the IP layer or configuration of the switches to prevent your computers talking to the rest of the network). Simple as that.

Comment: Can you recommend some documentation regarding how nothing magical happens in virtaulisation?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a load of bull to me, if you refer to the documentation of vmware tools you will see that it says it solves issues as:

- Low video resolution
- Inadequate color depth
- Incorrect display of network speed
- Restricted movement of the mouse
- Inability to copy and paste and drag-and-drop files
- Missing sound

There is a difference between not showing the right speed and not working at all. I think the problem is on their side. They are probably not routing for the 10.x.x.x subnet or they have ACL's in place that are preventing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with Jupiter. It is definitively a problem with 192.168.2.1 router.